# Typescript error when use react useState hook with generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When I use generic type in react useState hook, I have a weird error:

```js
// From react typings
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
declare function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];


// Declare generic response type
type TDataResponse<T> = { type: 'success'; data: T; };
type TErrorResponse = { type: 'error'; error: string; };
type TResponse<T> = TDataResponse<T> | TErrorResponse;

function loadData<T, U = TResponse<T>>() {
    const [data, setData] = useState<U | null>(null);

    // ERROR: Argument of type '{ type: string; error: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<U | null>'.
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'type' does not exist in type '(prevState: U | null) => U | null'.(2345)
    setData({ type: 'error', error: 'error message'});
}
```

But if use `useState<TResponse<T> | null>` there is no error:

```js
function loadData2<T, U = TResponse<T>>() {
    const [data2, setData2] = useState<TResponse<T> | null>(null);

    // No error
    setData2({ type: 'error', error: 'error message'});
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgIgQ2AgShAzmA9gO3RAHhgD4oBeKAbylEgC4oBydAVwGM2N1GBuKAEyQIGMPgF8eAKFrQYAUQBOCrArSZc+clRrgIDRhCUreUQ8oUN0wBQEscAc3FSZsNdjyESW+ELcbPpAA+sIrmfh5S0rpQAMoQwDHIwBAAgmzANrgEMaQUMVDBABSFYAoQAG6JSHqxAJTkpDG1ztFwNphIbAAWBCm5UIXlCAA2LDUp9WSk5Vg2-FL8EGzDCGVQAGYsOOmZOFAs+FXJ2cSFdjYZI0c1+UWFk421tQwA2jEANFBtHcDd2fHXNIZLI5YgAXUim22wL2wywCH4iGQRE+AFVvOF8ERiKd6pRJFBCVA2BpgFAXoJkJ98MAkQgwVoDhBrgR0cEcCxhsNThyuc1JASiQB6IVQFIKewsAC2EBwZKw6x0kCY1BklmsdkcpiMFigVlsDnEjCg7SgOCwZIQ6HQNnsOAQACNhtBgFgoGBVggZckFFAFUroIw4gkkqkdlk2WbOdzGAA6QWEkVQADyDoAVksycMLoYRlApQgQH6cMMi5gljZ1kWANbmgDue1KWEgCgyGE+CBw-CYMmN-CwGDNFtMAA92mS7AGmCUypVQwxI7zhg8oIvo3HCgAmADMABYAKy1BN6+J0wqq3T6MzGT7X3UGHX5rgIewQRhifliAVQ8Ow+GIoRNxRVcMQwdwsRIXEqGPEk8DJClAOpU9AIZCgmRZGBMQCAooy5Hlo35Y8kwAOTdO9jxpOlN3PAMrx1Rhbx1OjzCfa0XzfD8pC-IA)

Comment: Hello; I think, when you depend of U and U is gotten only in run-time, ts coudn't know what is U unless the generic function is executed and U is passed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not weird at all - in given syntax (`function loadData<T, U = TResponse<T>>() {...}`) the `U` type can be "anything" - so it's not possible for TypeScript to know what may it be during the runtime as only `U` sub-types are assignable to it, and the `{ type: 'error', error: 'error message'}` is not a sub-type of `U`

it won't get any better if you will change the definition to `function loadData<T, U extends TResponse<T> = TResponse<T>>() {...}`, because situation is the same, the `U` type just got narrower though

in situation like this one you can't use generics for internal values (so the correct definition would be just `function loadData<T>() {...}`), unless you somehow get the `U` type from somewhere, eg.

```js
function loadData<T, U = TResponse<T>>(loader: () => U) {
  const [data, setData] = useState<U | null>(null)

  setData(loader());
}

loadData<number>(() => ({ type: 'error', error: 'it works, lol' }))
```

Comment: Thanks Roomy, could I ask you, why ts after the narrowing by extends doesnt work either? it is not clear for me...and I just to know about more. thanks in advance

Comment: that's a good question, my understanding of that goes like: it doesn't matter, it's like picking a subset of types of an infinite amount of possible types, so the result of types still will be infinite - so we are forced to use concrete types here, does it helps?